# Send post request with data ( no json) in volley android

Tags: android, android-volley

In android I send post request ( use volley) but data not in json.
Example

```
 POST /info HTTP/1.1
 Host: test.com
 Cookie: test_web=1234;
 Connection: keep-alive
 Content-Length: 10

 id=123
```

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Help you with what?

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score -1):

Use ION library

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
}
```

usage:

```
Ion.with(getContext())
.load("https://koush.clockworkmod.com/test/echo")
.setBodyParameter("goop", "noop")
.setBodyParameter("foo", "bar")
.asString()
.setCallback(...)
```

**further information in**
https://github.com/koush/ion